# MySQL: difference of two result sets

Tags: mysql, set-difference

How can I get the set difference of two result sets?

Say I have a result set (just one column in each):

```
result1:
'a'
'b'
'c'

result2:
'b'
'c'
```

I want to minus what is in result1 by result2: result1 - result2 such that it equals:

```
 difference of result1 - result2:
 'a'
```

Answer (score 68, accepted):

To perform result1 - result2, you can join result1 with result2, and only output items that exist in result1. For example:

```
SELECT DISTINCT result1.column
FROM result1 LEFT JOIN result2 ON result1.column = result2.column
WHERE result2.column IS NULL
```

In set theory terms this is a *set difference* of result1 and result2, i.e. elements in result1 but not in result2.

If you are looking for a *symmetric difference* (elements in either result1 or result2, but not both), you can do a `FULL OUTER JOIN` and filter out elements where either side is `NULL`.

Finally, as a caveat, this won't work well if you have nullable columns in your database, as these will be seen identically to a row where the join failed. Thankfully, joins are normally performed on indexed columns, where nullable values are rare.

See also: [Web archive'd version of relevant blog post](http://web.archive.org/web/20151010010741/http://www.bitbybit.dk/carsten/blog/?p=71).

Comment: Thanks for your clarification, it's been a while since I've worked with MySQL.

Comment: It's really a [set difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)#Relative_complement), and what you called is just [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) which can be achieved by `FULL OUTER JOIN`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4796872/how-can-i-do-a-full-outer-join-in-mysql

Comment: Thanks for providing the proper terminology! I will update.

Answer (score 17):

If you want things in `result1` that are not in `result2`, what about:

```
SELECT distinct result1
FROM t1 
WHERE result1 NOT IN (select distinct result2 from t2);
```

Or:

```
SELECT distinct result
from t1 t
where NOT EXISTS (select 1 from t2 where result2 = t.result1)
```

NOTE: if `result1` is  a subset of `result2` then the above queries will return an empty set (they won't show you things in `result2` that are not in `result1`) so they are not set difference, but may be useful too (probably it's more efficient than the outer  join).

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this requirement where I had to find the difference between two resultsets. Although the above answers helped me wished they were a little detailed. For the given question I found two interpretation:

1. The resultset could be from 2 different tables
2. The resultset from the same table

For the first one where the resultset can be from 2 different tables, let's take two tables: **science_student** and **math_student**.

**science_student** 
[image]

**math_student** 
[image]

I want to calculate the difference between these 2 resultsets, that is:

```
result1 - result2

result1: select student_id from science_student where id > 2

result2: select student_id from math_student
```

The difference between result1 - result2 is STUD3

So the query to find the difference will be:

```
select result1.student_id 
 from 
 (select student_id from science_student where id > 2) result1
 left join
 (select student_id from math_student) result2
 on result1.student_id = result2.student_id 
 where result2.student_id is null;
```

For the second interpretation where the resultset can be from the same table:

```
result1 - result2

result1: select student_id from science_student 

result2: select student_id from science_student where id > 2
```

The difference between result1 - result2 is STUD1, STUD2

And the query for the same will be:

```
select result1.student_id 
 from 
 (select student_id from science_student) result1
 left join
 (select student_id from science_student where id > 2) result2
 on result1.student_id = result2.student_id 
 where result2.student_id is null;
```